# Implementing a JScrollPane to Scroll through a list of JLabels and JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, scrollpane

I am a student making a scatterplot program that uses user-made datasets. Each dataset is a collection of entries, with a Name, X value, Y value, and Subset (string). I want to make a JFrame scroll window where the user can scroll through a list of sorted entries to delete and possibly edit them, i have attached a basic illisturation to help explain what im looking to create. My Question is how would i go about doing this? Should i use some kind of container to house rectanglular data panes that i create? My UI experience is fairly limited as i am just a student so appologies if i dont understand[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each dataset is a collection of entries, with a Name, X value, Y value, and Subset (string). I want to make a JFrame scroll window where the user can scroll through a list of sorted entries to delete and possibly edit them,

I would use a `JTable`. It is a Swing component designed to display data in a row/column format. A `JTable` supports editing of the data and rows of data can easily be removed from the table when you use the `DefaultTableModel`.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.